# Can I run both my wordpress website and non-wordpress website on same domain?

Tags: php, wordpress

I build a client website and business system using html+php+mysql and both runs on same domain.

Recently, I feel like it would be better to separate the website and use wordpress so that the client can update their own contents instead of me doing this everytime they need to change something.

As, my client is in low budget, I was thinking whether it would be possible to run both the wordpress and business solution on same domain. If I run the business solution under sub-domain will it solve the issue or wordpress’s front controller will pickup any request related to that domain?

Is it possible at all? My suggestion would be appreciated.

many thanks,

Mahbub

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's absolutely possible, yes. And there are many scenarios you can use depending on what you want to do:

- Subdomains — install everything in different subdomains, or install one thing at the root and the others in different subdomains. The subdomains normally just map into directories on the same account, so you use the same FTP credentials and so on to transfer files.
- Directories — like http://www.example.com/blog. Very easy to deploy a blog this way, and just put your other stuff in the root.
- Intermingling — you can actually put files (.php, .html, etc.) in the same directory as WordPress, just as long as there are no name conflicts. The default redirection rules in .htaccess will ensure that those files will get served as usual without interfering with WordPress.

Not knowing anything about your code, if it's simple enough another approach would be to create custom page templates in WordPress that invoke your code. The nice thing about this is that your pages will always have the same look and feel as the other pages in the blog, i.e. if you change/update the theme. This may or may not matter to you.

Comment: If I add another directory's URL in wordpress navigation using custom URL. It navigates to that page correctly (which is outside the WordPress installation), but shows the page title as "Page Not Found". Do you have any pointers to fix this issue?

Answer (score 2):

Its possible. We have implemented it for multiple sites in the following ways

- Elgg as Master
- FluxBB / PhpBB for forum
- Wordpress for blogs

You can then share the sessions between these systems. Just process your login/ registration through only one system.

Answer (score 1):

Sure, you can set the wordpress site in for example: http://blog.example.com and the website in http://www.example.com without any problem. Just need to setup that in the web server.

Answer (score 0):

I did it by putting the wordpress blog in a separate directory inside the large domain.  wordpress do not interfere with other php sites on the same domain.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's possible.
We'd used Drupal for main website, ELGG for social networking, PHPBB3 for forums and Wordpress for blogging on the same domain name. We did it by using different subdomains for each site.